# error TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>'. Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<any>'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the HTTP library in angular  and I want to get some information from a link that has a JSON file, but it doesn't work for me

api.server.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
    getData(){
      return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    }
}
```

myapp.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.css']
})
export class MyappComponent implements OnInit {
  posts$: object;
  constructor( private api: ApiService) { 
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit(){

    this.api.getData().subscribe(
      api => this.posts$ = api
    )
  }
}
```

myapp.html:

```
<div class="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="images/TapIcon.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
            Medium.co
          </a>
          <ul class="navbar">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="OurStory.html">Our story</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="Articles.html">Articles</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <h1> posts</h1>
      <div class= "posts" *ngFor="let post of posts$">
        <div class="post">
          <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <div>{{post.body}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to use:

```
<div class= "posts" *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
```

but doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly specified the type of posts$ as object so the strict type checking of Angular templates doesn't like it because ngFor requires an iterable.

I recommend using the async pipe in your template as you indicated you tried, then change your component to look something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.css']
})
export class MyappComponent implements OnInit {
  posts$: Observable<Post>;
  constructor( private api: ApiService) { 
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.posts$ = this.api.getData();
  }

}
```

Doing it this way the async pipe will take care of subscribing to the observable returned by the api.  You could probably benefit from making the api more strongly typed.